# Turn off Saxon output to console

Tags: java, .net, saxon

When we use Saxon we sometimes get output to the console like:

Warning on line 2 column 6 
  in {\n\t\t\t\ttrue\n\t\t\t\tBest}:
    The expression is looking for a child element named 'true' - perhaps true() was
  intended? To avoid this warning, use child::true or ./true.
Warning on line 2 column 6 
  in {... Alternatives}:
    The expression is looking for a child element named 'false' - perhaps false() was
  intended? To avoid this warning, use child::false or ./false.

Is there a way to turn this off? Is there also a way to feed it to the log4j/log4net instance we are using?

We create a compiler as follows (we're doing XPath 2.0 queries in code - Java & .NET):

```
XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlData);
SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(reader, xmlSource);
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(schemaFile);
Configuration config = createEnterpriseConfiguration();
config.addSchemaSource(schemaSource);
Processor processor = new Processor(config);
SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidatorImpl(processor);

DocumentBuilder doc_builder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
if (!preserveWhiteSpace)
    doc_builder.setWhitespaceStrippingPolicy(WhitespaceStrippingPolicy.ALL);
doc_builder.setSchemaValidator(validator);
XdmNode root_node = doc_builder.build(saxSource);
XPathCompiler compiler = processor.newXPathCompiler();
compiler.setSchemaAware(true);
```

I can't give a logging filename because we want this to be in the log4j/log4net logs we're creating. Those might be a file, but they can be lots of other things and we want it to go to whatever logging listeners the user has configured.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Bug ATE-1221 (internal note)

Comment: So how do you use Saxon, I guess you need to share the relevant code to allow others to make suggestions on how to redirect messages. Of course that particular warning there tells you how to avoid it. https://saxonica.com/html/documentation/configuration/config-features.html lists `STANDARD_­ERROR_­OUTPUT_­FILE` as a configuration for instance

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I added the code above. Providing a filename won't work well for us because we want to send those warnings to the log4j/log4net stream, which may not be a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These messages are sent to the registered `ErrorListener`, calling its `warning()` method. In the case of free-standing XPath evaluation, this will be the `ErrorListener` registered with the `Configuration`. You can redirect this in several ways:

(a) you could write your own `ErrorListener` that does anything it wants (perhaps by subclassing the standard one)

(b) you could get the `StandardErrorListener` registered with the `Configuration` and call its `setLogger()` method to redirect its output to your own implementation of `net.sf.saxon.lib.Logger` (perhaps one that invokes log4j).

(c) you could continue to use the `StandardLogger`, used by the `StandardErrorListener` but redirect its output to a different `PrintStream`.

Unfortunately whereas XSLT and XQuery allow this to be controlled at the level of an individual transformation or query, for free-standing XPath it has to be configuration-wide.

**AFTERTHOUGHT**

I should have mentioned that these specific warnings can also be suppressed using the configuration option `FeatureKeys.SUPPRESS_XPATH_WARNINGS`

Comment: Could you please point me to an example of how to implement options a or b? I figure I can then send the messages to our log4j logger. thanks - dave

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample implementation, valid since Saxon 9.9.0-1: Define a *NullErrorListener*:

```
import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

/** Does nothing on errors (especially, does not log) */
public class NullErrorListener implements ErrorListener {
    @Override public void warning(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException { }
    @Override public void error(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException { }
    @Override public void fatalError(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException { }
}
```

Setting this ErrorListener is done by:

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
processor.setConfigurationProperty(net.sf.saxon.lib.Feature.ERROR_LISTENER_CLASS,
                                   NullErrorListener.class.getName());
```